# DAX measure not returning an expected value

Tags: powerbi, dax

The data model looks like this:
[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPJKT.png)

I need four key measures:

1. **Industry Standard**
   This one returns the value of industry (Table: 'Industry - Data') index basing on filtered **Ticker** (Table:'SP500 - Companies Info') and **Date** (Table: 'SP500 - Index Data')

> ```
> Ind. Stand. = 
>
> VAR SelectedTicker = SELECTEDVALUE('SP500 - Companies Info'[Ticker])
> VAR SelectedIndustry = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         MAX('SP500 - Companies Info'[Industry]),
>         'SP500 - Companies Info'[Ticker] = SelectedTicker
>     )
>
> VAR MinDate = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         MIN('SP500 - Index Data'[Date])
>     )
>
> VAR TotalAdjustedClosePrice = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         SUM('Industry - Data'[Value]),
>         ALL('Industry - Data'),
>         'Industry - Data'[Industry] = SelectedIndustry,
>         'Industry - Data'[Date] = MinDate
>     )
>     
> RETURN
>     TotalAdjustedClosePrice
> ```

It works fine.

2. **Industry Standard Data**
   The measure compares industry index value for each day with the **1. Industry Standard**. It gives clear information about the percentage growth/decline of index value for each day.

> ```
> Ind. Stand. Data = 
>
> VAR SelectedTicker = SELECTEDVALUE('SP500 - Companies Info'[Ticker])
>
> VAR SelectedIndustry = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         MAX('SP500 - Companies Info'[Industry]),
>         'SP500 - Companies Info'[Ticker] = SelectedTicker
>     )
>
> VAR TotalAdjustedClosePrice =
>     SUMX(
>         FILTER(
>             'Industry - Data',
>             'Industry - Data'[Industry] = SelectedIndustry
>         ),
>         CALCULATE(
>             SUM('Industry - Data'[Value])
>         )
>     )
>
> RETURN
>     DIVIDE(
>         TotalAdjustedClosePrice,
>         [Ind. Stand.]
>     ) -1
> ```

So I wanted to do the same for the ticker's value and then I can compare specific ticker's performance vs industry performance over time.

3. **Ticker Standard**
   It works similar as the **Industry Standard**. It returns the ticker's value for the minimum filtered date.

> ```
> Ticker Stand. = 
>
> VAR MinSelectedDate = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         MIN('SP500 - Index Data'[Date]),
>         ALLSELECTED('Tickers - Adjusted Close Price')
>     )
>
> VAR TickerStand = 
>     CALCULATE(
>         VALUES('Tickers - Adjusted Close Price'[Adjusted Close Price]),
>         'SP500 - Index Data'[Date] = MinSelectedDate
>     )
>
> RETURN
>     TickerStand
> ```

It works as it should.

4. **Ticker Standard Data**
   The problem begins with this one. It seems like the measure sums up all the filtered value of the tickers instead od calculating the % difference between the first filtered value and value for each day.

> ```
> Ticker Stand. Data = 
>
> VAR SelectedTicker = SELECTEDVALUE('SP500 - Companies Info'[Ticker])
>
> VAR TotalAdjustedClosePrice =
>     SUMX(
>         FILTER(
>             'Tickers - Adjusted Close Price',
>             'Tickers - Adjusted Close Price'[Ticker] = SelectedTicker
>         ),
>         CALCULATE(
>             SUM('Tickers - Adjusted Close Price'[Adjusted Close Price])
>         )
>     )
>
> RETURN
>     DIVIDE(
>         TotalAdjustedClosePrice,
>         [Ticker Stand.]
>     ) -1
> ```

What can I do to get the expected result?
Is it something about relationships between the tables or the measure is bad itself?

@EDIT:
I have noticed that when I change the [Date] from the table **Industry data** to **SP500 - Index Data** then the two first measures don't work, but these about Ticker data works well. So maybe it is about filters.

Comment: Hard to read your data model. Review your relationships, for example `Calendar` <--> `SP500 - Index Data` is 1.1, should it be 1.* ? Perhaps also look-up "[Star Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema)" - your model could benefit from it.